# Rails Active Storage push to DigitalOcean Spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Hi I'm trying to get active storage to push to a DigitalOcean space.  However, I'm finding that the push url is being changed to amazonaws.com even though I've defined the endpoint to digital ocean.

here is what I have in storage.yml

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: sfo2
  bucket: redacted_bucket_name
  endpoint: https://sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

When I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
Aws::Errors::NoSuchEndpointError (Encountered a `SocketError` while attempting to connect to:

  https://redacted_bucket_name.s3.sfo2.amazonaws.com/a8278561714955c23ee99
```

in my gemfile I have: `gem 'aws-sdk-s3`

I've followed the directions found [here](https://gorails.com/episodes/direct-uploads-with-rails-active-storage), and I'm still getting the error.  Is it possible that there's a new way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set something like this up myself a few days ago. When you check the URL `https://redacted_bucket_name.s3.sfo2.amazonaws.com/a8278561714955c23ee99` it's different from the actual endpoint you set up `https://redacted_bucket_name.sfo2.amazonaws.com/a8278561714955c23ee99`

the error is being caused by an invalid endpoint your hitting, the `s3` right before the `.sfo2` is offsetting the endpoint. Did you happen to add `s3` to your spaces config? check your spaces dashboard and try to get the endpoint setup properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same challenge when working on a Rails 6 application in Ubuntu 20.04.

**Here's how I fixed mine**:

Firstly, create a **Spaces access keys** in your digital ocean console. This link should help - [DigitalOcean Spaces API](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/account/api)

Secondly, add a new configuration for DigitalOcean Spaces in your `config/storage.yml` file. Just after the `local` storage definition:

```
# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
digital_ocean:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= SPACES_ACCESS_KEY_ID %>
  secret_access_key: <%= SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY %>
  region: <%= SPACES_REGION %>
  bucket: <%= SPACES_BUCKET_NAME %>
  endpoint: <%= SPACES_ENDPOINT %>
```

**Note**: You can give your entry any name, say `digital_ocean_spaces` or something else. For me I named it `digital_ocean`.

Thirdly, modify the `config.active_storage.service` configuration in the `config/environments/production.rb` file from:

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

to

```
config.active_storage.service = :digital_ocean
```

Finally, specify these environment variables file in your `config/application.yml` file (if you're using the **Figaro** gem) or your `.env` file. (if you're using the **dotenv** gem). In my case I was using the **dotenv** gem, so my `.env` file looked looked like this:

```
SPACES_ACCESS_KEY_ID=E4TFWVPDBLRTLUNZEIFMR
SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BBefjTJTFHYVNThun7GUPCeT2rNDJ4UxGLiSTM70Ac3NR
SPACES_REGION=nyc3
SPACES_BUCKET_NAME=my-spaces
SPACES_ENDPOINT=https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**